# Is it possible for the Braintree Drop-In UI PayPal button pop-up to work on a webpage that is displayed inside an Adobe AIR desktop app?

Tags: paypal, air, popup, braintree

We have a web page that uses the Braintree Drop-In UI. If I visit the page in a normal browser like Chrome, then the pop-up for the PayPal button works properly.

But we want to use this page inside our Adobe AIR desktop app. When you view the page in AIR everything is fine except the PayPal button pop-up doesn't appear on click, so PayPal is essentially disabled.

Why doesn't the pop-up work? I was trying to find the code for the pop-up but I think it is buried somewhere in here:

https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

`braintree.js` is currently [not supported](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/browser-support#webviews) in compile-to-native runtimes. I'd suggest investigating the Adobe AIR documentation to determine how it handles pop-ups.